# Test for ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

My application is propagating a ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound to the controller when a model can't retrieve a record.

Here is the DB query:

```
def self.select_intro_verse
  offset = rand(IntroVerse.count)
  IntroVerse.select('line_one', 'line_two', 'line_three', 'line_four', 'line_five').offset(offset).first!.as_json
end
```

`first!` raises a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if no record is found, and I am able to rescue it and render an appropriate template in my controller.

This is the expected behavior so I would like to have a test for it in my specs. I wrote:

```
context "verses missing in database" do
  it "raises an exception" do
    expect(VerseSelector.select_intro_verse).to raise_exception
  end
end
```

When I run rspec:

`1) VerseSelector verses missing in database raises an exception
     Failure/Error: expect(VerseSelector.select_intro_verse).to raise_exception
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`

To me the test fails even though the exception is raised! How can I make my test pass?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Look  in documentation for [`rspec-expectations#expecting-errors`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations#expecting-errors) this:

```
expect(VerseSelector.select_intro_verse).to raise_exception
```

should be `except` syntax for exception must be `lambda` or `proc`:

```
expect { VerseSelector.select_intro_verse }.to raise_exception(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
```

Comment: _must be lambda or proc_ - should be bolded :)